# Замыкания в функциях

Tags: javascript, замыкания

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr.filter(function() {
  return function(x) {
    return x == 3
  }
})
```

Почему вывод целый массив? Если убрать одну функцию , то все ок. Вопрос касательно замыканий.Вложенная функция имеет доступ ко всему,что выше

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никаких замыканий здесь нет. Для каждого элемента массива Вы возвращаете из обработчика, поданного в `filter`, анонимную функцию `function(x) { ... }`, не вызывая ее. (Ее вообще никто не вызывает.) Булевское значение, соответствующее ссылке на функцию, - `true`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x == 3
}));

console.log(arr.filter((x) => x == 3));
```

Answer (score 4):

Всё очень просто. Фильтрующая функция должна возвращать true или false для каждого элемента массива. Те элементы, для которых вернётся true, будут добавлены в результирующий массив, остальные будут отброшены. А что возвращает ваша фильтрующая функция? Она возвращает анонимную функцию! Не true, не false, функцию! При приведении типа функция выглядит скорее как true, чем false (`console.log(Boolean(function() {}));`). И значит все элементы исходного массива добавятся в результат фильтрации.